# trees and tables in DB2

Tags: sql, database, tree, db2

I would like your help about this graph which I have.I would like to find a way how write a script to create a table named COMPS to represent this component/subcomponent
tree structure, as an edge list for the graph. I can use these names for the columns of the table COMPONENT, SUBCOMPONENT, SUBCOMPCOUNT. Any ideas?

Components of type b occur in more than one place in the structure of
component a. But the structure of component b is the same, regardless of its position
Component d also occurs in various different locations, but all objects of type d are the
same kind of object
[image]

Comment: no....this is something for me..how to work in this kind of exercises I mean!

Comment: tips for reading are 'Joe Celko's Trees and Hierarchies in SQL for Smarties'  and  '[Storing Hierarchical Data in a Database](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/hierarchical-data-database)'

Answer (score 0):

You should create a table as you say in order to store the structue

```
create table graph (
ID int not null,
COMPONENT char(2) not null,
ParentComponent int)
```

Create a primary key for ID column. And a foreign key for parentComponent referencing the same table with the ID column.

Then, you can create a set of UDF and stored procedure to retrieve values, or to print the tree structure. For example, UDFs for

- Retrieve the root node
- Quantity of nodes in the tree
- Quantity of sons of a given node
- The Parent ID of a given node.

And Stored procedures for

- Return a table with the rows ordered by a specific tree traversal (Breadth-first, Depth-first)

You can even create check constraints to provide rules to create the graph. For example, root node is 0, no one else can have this ID, and the is the lowest value.

What operations do you need to do in you graph?